# TensorFlow Multiple Import Errors

Tags: tensorflow

First Time installing Tensor flow and when trying to import i am receiving multiple errors as below.

OS: Win7 x64

Installation method: Native

Installation result: Success

Python Version: 3.5.2

Following youtube video for installation :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BtDgICVvkHE

Please let me know if any further details are required.

```
C:\>python
Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:18:55) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AM
D64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\XX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
        return importlib.import_module(mname)
    File "C:\Users\XX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 906, in create_module
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
C:\>python
Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:18:55) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AM
D64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\XX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
        return importlib.import_module(mname)
    File "C:\Users\XX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 906, in create_module
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\XX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
        from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
    File "C:\Users\XX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
        _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
    File "C:\Users\XX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
        return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
    File "C:\Users\XX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\XX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
        from tensorflow.python import *
    File "C:\Users\XX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
        from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
    File "C:\Users\XX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
        raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\XX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
        return importlib.import_module(mname)
    File "C:\Users\XX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 906, in create_module
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\XX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
        from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
    File "C:\Users\XX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
       _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
    File "C:\Users\XX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
        return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
    File "C:\Users\XX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace above this error message when asking for help.
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, this is due to missing DLLs (or missing paths thereto). You can use the script [here](https://gist.github.com/mrry/ee5dbcfdd045fa48a27d56664411d41c) to figure out which one.

Comment: Thanks i'll give it a go !

Answer (score 0):

Main issues was the Missing DLL's which can be resolved by installing vc_redist.x64.exe

I now have TF successfully installed.